# ajax success is not working when i want the upload the file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code. i want to upload the image file using ajax, php. when the image file is uploaded it should show the preview. The image file is successfully uploading but the ajax success is not showing the preview.

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class='preview'>
       <img src="" id="photo_disp" width="100" height="100">
    </div>  
     <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" accept=".jpeg,.jpg" required/>          
     <button type="submit" id="btn_photo" name="submit">Upload Photo</button>                
</form>
```

Here is the ajax i have used. The ajax is successfully posting the file to php code but the success response is not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','#btn_photo',function(){           
    var fd = new FormData();
    var files = $('#file1')[0].files;
            // Check file selected or not
            if(files.length > 0 )
            {
                fd.append('file',files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax_photo.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        alert(response);
                        if(response != 0)
                        {
                            $("#photo_disp").attr("src",response);                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('File not uploaded');
                        }
                    }
                });
              }
              else
              {
                alert("Please select a file.");
              }
       });
</script>
```

Here is my php code using on click

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
  {
   session_start();   
   $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $roll=$_SESSION['name'];  
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);    
   $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg");
    $response = 0;      
   if(in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions))
   {
     $location = "upload/".$roll.".".$imageFileType;            
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location))
     {
        $response = $location;
     }
   }
  echo $response;
  exit;
}
  echo 0;
?>
```

Please find out where i did the mistake. The image is successfully uploading to the given path but the image is not showing in the preview. i have written an alter in the success. But the alert is also not working.

Comment: do you want to preview image before or after upload ?

Comment: after upload of the file

Comment: then you can simply get the path of the image where you are saving image and show it in an image tag , why you want to do this in ajax response

Comment: What response do you observe in the console?

Comment: What should reponse look like? You ask `response != 0` and if it is then you set it to src,.

Comment: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://nriitexamcell.com/stdinfo/test/jquery.min.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: my idea is to set to src of the preview of the image . But its not happening. If the response =0 then the file is not moved to the desired location

Comment: I don't see how anything in the posted code could throw that error. Check the stack trace and find out what in your code triggers that error.

Comment: The url cited above has no ajax

Comment: As @ProfessorAbronsius lamented, *the URL cited has no ajax*. Just a note, your images in the URL link provided aren't displaying because you're missing a forward slash (*/*) in front of your image `src` attribute values. I.e: `<img src="/logo.png" width="97%" draggable="false">` , `<img src="/jntuk.png" height="30%" width="30%" draggable="false">` , `<img src="/nriit.jpg" height="30%" width="40%" draggable="false">`

Answer (score 0):

If the response refers to a fully qualified resource path (*https:example.com/upload/cat-dancing.jpg*) on the server, you can assign it directly to the image's `src` attribute just like you've done in your question.

> `$("#photo_disp").attr("src",response);`

If the returned resource path doesn't contain the domain name (*upload/cat-dancing.jpg*), prepend it with a forward slash to indicate that the path starts from the document root of the website. I.e:

`$("#photo_disp").attr("src", "/" + response);`

Otherwise, if the response is an actual File or Blob, you could set the image's `src` attribute using:

```js
const img =  $("#photo_disp").get(0);
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(response);
img.height = 60;
img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
}
```

> 1. Set the image's source to a new object URL representing the file, using
>    [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
>    to create the blob URL.
> 2. Set the image's height to 60 pixels.
> 3. Set up the image's load event handler to release the object URL since it's no longer needed once the image has been loaded. This is
>    done by calling the
>    [URL.revokeObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)
>    method and passing in the object URL string as specified by `img.src`.

##### Resource:

[Example: Using object URLs to display images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_using_object_urls_to_display_images)